# Unarchiving custom objects in Swift using generics

Tags: swift, generics, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm trying to write code to unarchive NSData into custom objects from NSUserDefaults, so far I've got this -

```
class func itemForKey<T>(key: String) -> T?
{
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var value : T?

    if let dataObj = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? NSData
    {
        value = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataObj) as? T
    }

    return value
}
```

Unfortunately, it returns garbage. If I switch out T for a class type at the point of unarchiving, the object is created correctly -

```
class func itemForKey<T>(key: String) -> T?
{
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var value : T?

    if let dataObj = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? NSData
    {
        let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataObj) as? CustomObject // correct at this point
```

but obviously this defeats the purpose of generics.

Any help, etc, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class func itemForKey<T>(key: String) -> T?
{
    if let dataObj = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? NSData {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataObj) as? T
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Sorry, effectively identical to what I've posted, doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to infer the class inside the method, you could also do so that the one who calls the method,

```
let item: MyClass? = SomeObject.itemForKey("SomeKey")
```

*Note: the item is declared with the type of MyClass, so compiler will infer the T from your method correctly,*

Comment: That's exactly how I'm calling it already, it just fails at the point of turning it into the correct type of object

Comment: It's also a cut-down version of the function (I posted only the relevant bit of code) - it's designed to work with all of NSUserDefaults functions, boolForKey, integerForKey, objectForKey, etc. Its usefulness would disappear if I relied on the caller

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but I don't really see why the old version doesn't work. The new code is -

```
class func itemForKey<T>(key: String) -> T?
{
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var value : T?

    if let dataObj = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? NSData
    {
        if let obj: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataObj)
        {
            value = obj as? T
        }
    }

    return value
}
```

If anyone has any idea why this works & the first version didn't, I'd be grateful to hear